# Cannot set property of "something" of undefined error while trying to create an array sorted by dates.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I posted a related question [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899951/how-can-i-sort-a-firebase-angularfire-array-into-weeks-and-days/25941189#25941189) and @Kato helped me out with an answer. I am attempting to implement his answer but getting an error of Cannot set property of "something" of undefined.

I made a plnkr to be as detailed as possible: http://plnkr.co/edit/M4zEjpZ4kqTKn1sHHMt6

```
//controller
angular.module('app').controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, DatedList) {
  $scope.world = 'world';

  var listRef = new Firebase("https://talllly.firebaseio.com/");
  $scope.weeks = DatedList(listRef);

  $scope.addTask = function(){
    listRef.push({    
      text: $scope.task.text,
      week: 40,
      day: 2  
    });   
  };


});       

angular.module('app').service('DatedList', function($timeout) {
  return function(pathToList) {
    var list = {};  

    pathToList.on('child_added', function(snap) {
      $timeout(function() { // force Angular to run $digest when changes occur
        var data = snap.val();
        console.log(data);
        var week_number = data.week;
        var week_day = data.day;
        list[week_number][week_day] = data;
      });
    });

    //todo: write similar processing for child_changed and child_removed

    return list;
  }  
});

//html
<form ng-submit="addTask()">
      <input placeholder="add task" ng-model="task.text">
    </form>
    <div ng-repeat="(week, days) in weeks">    
     <h1>{{week}}</h1>
     <div ng-repeat="(day, items) in days">
        <h2>{{day}}</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
           {{item|json}}
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize `list[week_number]`:

```
pathToList.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  $timeout(function() { // force Angular to run $digest when changes occur
    var data = snap.val();
    console.log(data);
    var week_number = data.week;
    var week_day = data.day;

    list[week_number] = {};  // <- Add this line here
    list[week_number][week_day] = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because you're trying to add a property to list[week_num] and it isn't an object.

You could do

```
list[week_number] = list[week_number] || {};
list[week_number][week_day] = data;
```

or

```
if(!angular.isObject(list[week_number]) {
    list[week_number] = {};
}
list[week_number][week_day] = data;
```