# What is the angularfire way of dealing with $priority?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am attempting to use an answer provided by Kato in this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899951/how-can-i-sort-a-firebase-angularfire-array-into-weeks-and-days) but do not understand the concept of utilizing priorities in angularfire. There is a very brief mention of priorities in the angularfire API docs but no examples.

Here's the Plnkr of my project so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/A8lDKbNvhcSzbWVrysVm

```
//controller
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function($firebase, $scope) {

  var ref = new Firebase('https://plnkr.firebaseio.com').startAt().endAt();
  var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
  $scope.list = list;
  console.log(list);

  var last = null;
  $scope.priorityChanged = function(priority) {
    var current = moment(priority).startOf('day');
    var changed = last === null || !last.isSame(current);
    last = current;
    return changed;
  };

  $scope.getDayName = function($priority) {
    return moment($priority).format('dddd');
  };

  $scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
    list.$add({
      title: newTask.title,
      timestamp: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    });
  };

});

//view
<form ng-submit="addTask(task); task.title=null">
 <input placeholder="Add Task" ng-model="task.title"/>
</form>

<li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-init="changed = priorityChanged(item.$priority)">
 <h3 ng-show="changed">{{getDayName(item.$priority)}}</h3>
 {{item | json}}  
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that plnkr has the 8.0 version of angularfire in their package manager. It works just fine in the latest version.

```
 $scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
    list.$add({
      title: newTask.title,
      $priority: 3
    });
  };
```